# Page refresh on form submit (vanilla javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, page-refresh

I'm learning about Javascript.... slowly... and tried to test my knowledge with a little calculator...

HTML:

```
<form id="calculator" onSubmit="multiply()">
<input type="number" id="first">
*
<input type="number" id="second">
<input type="submit"> = <span id="answer"></span>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function multiply() {
    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var z = x * y;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
}
```

The problem I've run into and have no idea about is why on form submit/button click/return key does the page refresh? What am I doing wrong? What is the answer in plain Javascript. I know the calculator works up to a point because the answer flashes on the page before it refreshes, but yet it does. Why?

(I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer in plain Javascript and/or with an explanation I could understand).

Comment: return something in form?

Answer (score 2):

Use return false in the method and modify on submit to return multiply().
Here is the script

```
function multiply() {
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var z = x * y;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
  return (false);
}
```

Here is the modified HTML

```
<form id="calculator" onSubmit="return multiply()" method="post">
  <input type="number" id="first"> *
  <input type="number" id="second">
  <input type="submit"> = <span id="answer"></span>
</form>
```

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/anuraj_p/sjvvod8q/

Answer (score 0):

Change type of "=" button to "button" i.e. set type = button. On "=" button click page is submitted to server after your calculations run on client side. The page is reloaded after submit that's why you see your result flashes for a second.

Answer (score 0):

In standard HTML, a form is an element that is designed to collect data via its contained inputs. Default behaviour is once data is entered and the form submitted, the browser sends all of that form data back to the server (POST request) and reloads the response. This is standard behaviour. If you want to run a JS function on submit, and stop if from refreshing the page you need to cancel the default behaviour. Usually this is via returning false or e.preventDefault (e is the event object that every JS event handler gets)

So something like

```
<form id="calculator" onSubmit="return multiply()">
<input type="number" id="first">
*
<input type="number" id="second">
<input type="submit"> = <span id="answer"></span>
</form>

function multiply(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var z = x * y;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

is usually whats done. Personally I try not to change default behavoir. If you are not sending data to the server, and are purely wanting to do some JS function, then you really don't need a form. Something like

Html:

```
<input type="number" id="first">
*
<input type="number" id="second">
<button type="button" onclick="multiply()">=</button> = 
<span id="answer"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
function multiply() {
        var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
        var z = x * y;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
    }
```

Makes more semantic sense to me. ANd better yet, don't put event handlers in line with your HTML

```
 <input type="number" id="first">
    *
    <input type="number" id="second">
    <button id="btnMultiply" type="button">=</button> = 
    <span id="answer"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementyId('btnMultiply').addEventListener('click',multiply);

function multiply() {
        var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
        var z = x * y;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
    }
```